# Python pdb (debugger) disp equivalent?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Is there a pdb equivalent to `disp` in gdb?

E.g. when I'm debugging C using gdb I can have variables printed on every 'step' through the code by typing:

```
disp var
```

When I'm debugging python using pdb I would like similar functionality, but `disp` does not seem to be there, the python pdb documentation does not seem to offer an alternative - but it seems like an odd omission?

Comment: perhaps ipdb has some alternative functionality

Comment: As an alternative, if you like a nice UI, you might want to use [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb).

Answer (score 3):

The code bellow uses Python introspection features to add two new commands to the PDB module 0
just put the given function, and its call in a separate module, and import this module before starting debugging - you should have the 'disp' and 'undisp' commands do add and retract watches to variables.

It works by monkeypatching Python's pdb module, which is written in pure python.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def patch_pdb():
    import pdb

    def wrap(func):
        def new_postcmd(self, *args, **kw):
            result = func(self, *args, **kw)
            if hasattr(self, "curframe") and self.curframe and hasattr(self, "watch_list"):
                for arg in self.watch_list:
                    try:
                        print >> self.stdout, "%s: %s"% (arg, self._getval(arg)) + ", ", 
                    except: 
                        pass
                self.stdout.write("\n")
            return result #func(self, *args, **kw)

        return new_postcmd

    pdb.Pdb.postcmd = wrap(pdb.Pdb.postcmd)

    def do_disp(self, arg):
        if not hasattr(self, "watch_list"):
            self.watch_list = []
        self.watch_list.append(arg)

    pdb.Pdb.do_disp = do_disp

    def do_undisp(self, arg):
        if hasattr(self, "watch_list"):
            try:
                self.watch_list.remove(arg)
            except:
                pass

    pdb.Pdb.do_undisp = do_undisp

patch_pdb()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # for testing
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    a = 0
    for i in range(10):
        print i
        a += 2
```

Unfortunately I could only make it display the state of the variables as they where previously to the execution of the last command. (I tried a little bit, but monkeypatching the bdb module, which is the base for the Pdb did not seem to work as well). You can try and change the methods in either pdb.Pdb, bdb.Bdb or cmd.Cmd that are decorated by `wrap` to find one that is called after the debugged frame state has changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up some aliases that will do this for you:

```
alias n next;; p var
alias s step;; p var
```

Printing a whole list of variable names is left as an exercise to the reader. Unfortunately doing it this way means that when you send the debugger an empty line, the "last command" it executes is `p var` rather than, for example, `n`. If you want to fix that, then you can use this somewhat hacky set of Pdb commands instead:

```
!global __stack; from inspect import stack as __stack
!global __Pdb; from pdb import Pdb as __Pdb
!global __pdb; __pdb = [__framerec[0].f_locals.get("pdb") or __framerec[0].f_locals.get("self") for __framerec in __stack() if (__framerec[0].f_locals.get("pdb") or __framerec[0].f_locals.get("self")).__class__ == __Pdb][-1]

alias s step;; p var;; !__pdb.lastcmd = "!__pdb.cmdqueue.append('s')"
alias n next;; p var;; !__pdb.lastcmd = "!__pdb.cmdqueue.append('n')"
```

Answer (score 1):

During the pdb debugging you can type normal python code, beyond the one letter commands - so just using `print var`  should work for you.

Comment: would that mean pdb would automatically reprint `var` each time I hit `s` or `n` then? Not sure that it would, seems the same as typing `p var` to me. The question isn't about how to print a variable using the debugger, more about how I can use pdb more efficiently/effectively...

Comment: Sorry - not - this only prints the variable once.